# docker within-container port forwarding

Tags: docker, portforwarding

Is there a way to forward one container-local port to another container-local port?

I know that

```
 docker run -d --name web_lb -p 8000:80 --link web_1:web_1 --link web_2:web_2 tutum/haproxy
```

forwards the host port 8000 to the container port 80, but how would  I forward the container's port 8000 to the container's port 80?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You normally wouldn't need to do that: any [EXPOSEd](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose) port in `web_1` is directly accessible by the running container.

If multiple identical ports are exposed in linked containers (like `web_1` and `web_2`), then the running container needs its own reverse proxy service (usually an NGiNX) to proxy-pass to one or the other.

Comment: I know that normally I would not need to do this, but I'm trying to add another load balancer behind the web front end. the problem is that the web front end code (which I don't want to touch) makes requests to port 8000 while Haproxy listens on port 80, so if I could just forward the load balancers port 8000 to 80 I think it will work

Comment: @Kdawg Hence the need of an intermediate container like nginx.

Comment: @Kdawg Maybe be this is closer to what you want: http://oskarhane.com/haproxy-as-a-static-reverse-proxy-for-docker-containers/

Comment: I'll take a stab at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27912917/how-to-configure-docker-port-mapping-to-use-nginx-as-an-upstream-proxy