# Error: Couldn't resolve host name in Rails application with Docker-compose and Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'm trying to get up a Rails application with docker-compose, postgres and nginx. The rails application is running healthly by its own. It's responing me accordingly as expected. But when I run it with my docker-compose, the nginx give me `Error: Couldn't resolve host name`. The curl response is:

```
➜ curl -v http://localhost:3002/clientes/1/extrato
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:3002...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 3002 (#0)
> GET /clientes/1/extrato HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:3002
> User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< location: https://localhost:3002/clientes/1/extrato
< Content-Length: 0
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Here all some of the main files:

docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: "3.5"

services:
  api01: &rails-api
    build: ./
    # image: mende1/rinha-backend-2024-q1:latest
    hostname: api01
    container_name: api01
    environment:
      DB_HOST: postgres
      RAILS_ENV: production
      RAILS_MAX_THREADS: 40
      WEB_CONCURRENCY: 2
      RAILS_LOG_LEVEL: warn
      RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT: "true"
      RAILS_MASTER_KEY: 2bd79f1e7739f06a17ada0b5af1773fb

    depends_on:
      - postgres
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.4"
          memory: "150MB"

  api02:
    <<: *rails-api
    container_name: api02
    hostname: api02

  nginx:
    image: nginx
    container_name: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    ports:
      - 9999:9999
    depends_on:
      - api01
      - api02
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.2"
          memory: "50MB"

  postgres:
    image: postgres:16.1
    container_name: postgres
    hostname: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: rinha
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    command: postgres -c 'max_connections=450'
    volumes:
      - ./script.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/script.sql
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 20
      start_period: 10s
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.5"
          memory: "200MB"

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
    name: rinha-nginx-2024q1
```

Dockerfile:

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:1

# Make sure RUBY_VERSION matches the Ruby version in .ruby-version and Gemfile
ARG RUBY_VERSION=3.2.3
FROM registry.docker.com/library/ruby:$RUBY_VERSION-bullseye as base

# Rails app lives here
WORKDIR /rails

# Set production environment
ENV RAILS_ENV="production" \
    BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT="1" \
    BUNDLE_PATH="/usr/local/bundle" \
    BUNDLE_WITHOUT="development"


# Throw-away build stage to reduce size of final image
FROM base as build

RUN echo "Acquire::http::Pipeline-Depth 0;" > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99custom && \
    echo "Acquire::http::No-Cache true;" >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99custom && \
    echo "Acquire::BrokenProxy    true;" >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99custom

# Install packages needed to build gems
RUN apt-get update -qq && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y build-essential git libpq-dev libvips pkg-config

# Install application gems
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN bundle install && \
    rm -rf ~/.bundle/ "${BUNDLE_PATH}"/ruby/*/cache "${BUNDLE_PATH}"/ruby/*/bundler/gems/*/.git && \
    bundle exec bootsnap precompile --gemfile

# Copy application code
COPY . .

# Precompile bootsnap code for faster boot times
RUN bundle exec bootsnap precompile app/ lib/


# Final stage for app image
FROM base

RUN echo "Acquire::http::Pipeline-Depth 0;" > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99custom && \
    echo "Acquire::http::No-Cache true;" >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99custom && \
    echo "Acquire::BrokenProxy    true;" >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99custom

# Install packages needed for deployment
RUN apt-get update -qq && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y curl libvips postgresql-client && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists /var/cache/apt/archives

# Copy built artifacts: gems, application
COPY --from=build /usr/local/bundle /usr/local/bundle
COPY --from=build /rails /rails

# Run and own only the runtime files as a non-root user for security
RUN useradd rails --create-home --shell /bin/bash && \
   chown -R rails:rails db log storage tmp
USER rails:rails

# Entrypoint prepares the database.
# ENTRYPOINT ["/rails/bin/entrypoint.sh"]

# Start the server by default, this can be overwritten at runtime
EXPOSE 3000 
CMD ["./bin/rails", "server"]
```

nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes auto;

events {
    worker_connections 256;
}

http {
    access_log off;

    upstream api {
        server api01:3000;
        server api02:3000;
    }

    server {
        listen 9999;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://api;
        }
    }
}
```

And here are the log of the docker-compose after got up:

```bash
➜ docker-compose up
[+] Running 5/4
 ✔ Network rinhabackend-2024-q1-rails_default  Created                                    0.0s 
 ✔ Container postgres                          Created                                    0.0s 
 ✔ Container api02                             Created                                    0.0s 
 ✔ Container api01                             Created                                    0.0s 
 ✔ Container nginx                             Created                                    0.0s 
Attaching to api01, api02, nginx, postgres
postgres  | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
postgres  | This user must also own the server process.
postgres  | 
postgres  | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
postgres  | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
postgres  | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
postgres  | 
postgres  | Data page checksums are disabled.
postgres  | 
postgres  | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
postgres  | creating subdirectories ... ok
postgres  | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
postgres  | selecting default max_connections ... 100
postgres  | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
postgres  | selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
postgres  | creating configuration files ... ok
postgres  | running bootstrap script ... ok
nginx     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
nginx     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
nginx     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
nginx     | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
nginx     | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Enabled listen on IPv6 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
nginx     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Sourcing /docker-entrypoint.d/15-local-resolvers.envsh
nginx     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
nginx     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
nginx     | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
postgres  | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
postgres  | syncing data to disk ... ok
postgres  | 
postgres  | 
postgres  | Success. You can now start the database server using:
postgres  | 
postgres  |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
postgres  | 
postgres  | initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
postgres  | initdb: hint: You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
postgres  | waiting for server to start....2024-02-09 14:03:36.502 UTC [48] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.1 (Debian 16.1-1.pgdg120+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
postgres  | 2024-02-09 14:03:36.504 UTC [48] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres  | 2024-02-09 14:03:36.512 UTC [51] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-02-09 14:03:36 UTC
postgres  | 2024-02-09 14:03:36.519 UTC [48] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
postgres  |  done
postgres  | server started
postgres  | CREATE DATABASE
postgres  | 
postgres  | 
postgres  | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/script.sql
postgres  | SET
postgres  | SET
postgres  | SET
postgres  | SET
postgres  | SET
postgres  |  set_config 
postgres  | ------------
postgres  |  
postgres  | (1 row)
postgres  | 
postgres  | SET
postgres  | SET
postgres  | SET
postgres  | SET
postgres  | SET
postgres  | SET
postgres  | CREATE TABLE
postgres  | CREATE TABLE
postgres  | CREATE SEQUENCE
postgres  | ALTER SEQUENCE
postgres  | CREATE TABLE
postgres  | CREATE TABLE
postgres  | CREATE SEQUENCE
postgres  | ALTER SEQUENCE
postgres  | ALTER TABLE
postgres  | ALTER TABLE
postgres  | ALTER TABLE
postgres  | ALTER TABLE
postgres  | ALTER TABLE
postgres  | ALTER TABLE
postgres  | CREATE INDEX
postgres  | ALTER TABLE
postgres  | SET
postgres  | INSERT 0 2
postgres  | INSERT 0 1
postgres  | INSERT 0 1
postgres  | INSERT 0 1
postgres  | INSERT 0 1
postgres  | INSERT 0 1
postgres  | 
postgres  | 
postgres  | waiting for server to shut down....2024-02-09 14:03:36.829 UTC [48] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
postgres  | 2024-02-09 14:03:36.831 UTC [48] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
postgres  | 2024-02-09 14:03:36.832 UTC [48] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 54) exited with exit code 1
postgres  | 2024-02-09 14:03:36.832 UTC [49] LOG:  shutting down
postgres  | 2024-02-09 14:03:36.834 UTC [49] LOG:  checkpoint starting: shutdown immediate
postgres  | 2024-02-09 14:03:36.871 UTC [49] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 945 buffers (5.8%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.013 s, sync=0.019 s, total=0.039 s; sync files=318, longest=0.008 s, average=0.001 s; distance=4336 kB, estimate=4336 kB; lsn=0/1926D68, redo lsn=0/1926D68
postgres  | 2024-02-09 14:03:36.876 UTC [48] LOG:  database system is shut down
api02     | => Booting Puma
api02     | => Rails 7.1.3 application starting in production 
api02     | => Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
api01     | => Booting Puma
api01     | => Rails 7.1.3 application starting in production 
api01     | => Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
postgres  |  done
postgres  | server stopped
postgres  | 
postgres  | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
postgres  | 
postgres  | 2024-02-09 14:03:36.952 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.1 (Debian 16.1-1.pgdg120+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
postgres  | 2024-02-09 14:03:36.952 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres  | 2024-02-09 14:03:36.952 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres  | 2024-02-09 14:03:36.956 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres  | 2024-02-09 14:03:36.962 UTC [66] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-02-09 14:03:36 UTC
postgres  | 2024-02-09 14:03:36.967 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
api01     | [1] Puma starting in cluster mode...
api01     | [1] * Puma version: 6.4.2 (ruby 3.2.3-p157) ("The Eagle of Durango")
api01     | [1] *  Min threads: 40
api01     | [1] *  Max threads: 40
api01     | [1] *  Environment: production
api01     | [1] *   Master PID: 1
api01     | [1] *      Workers: 2
api01     | [1] *     Restarts: (✔) hot (✖) phased
api01     | [1] * Preloading application
api01     | [1] * Listening on http://0.0.0.0:3000
api01     | [1] Use Ctrl-C to stop
api02     | [1] Puma starting in cluster mode...
api02     | [1] * Puma version: 6.4.2 (ruby 3.2.3-p157) ("The Eagle of Durango")
api02     | [1] *  Min threads: 40
api02     | [1] *  Max threads: 40
api02     | [1] *  Environment: production
api02     | [1] *   Master PID: 1
api02     | [1] *      Workers: 2
api02     | [1] *     Restarts: (✔) hot (✖) phased
api02     | [1] * Preloading application
api02     | [1] * Listening on http://0.0.0.0:3000
api02     | [1] Use Ctrl-C to stop
api02     | [1] - Worker 0 (PID: 9) booted in 0.0s, phase: 0
api02     | [1] - Worker 1 (PID: 11) booted in 0.0s, phase: 0
api01     | [1] - Worker 0 (PID: 9) booted in 0.06s, phase: 0
api01     | [1] - Worker 1 (PID: 11) booted in 0.06s, phase: 0
```

Comment: nginx inside it's container isn't aware of the host api01. take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27912917/how-to-configure-docker-port-mapping-to-use-nginx-as-an-upstream-proxy